# Number of unique pairs in an array - in php

Tags: php

**Input**: arr[] = {1, 1, 2} ;
**Output**: 4 ;
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2) are the only possible pairs.

I tried below code

```
$temp = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
    for($j=1;$j<count($a);$j++) {
       $temp[] = array(0=>$a[$i],1=>$a[$j]);
    }
}
for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++) {
  if(!empty($temp1)) {
    for($j=0;$j<count($temp1);$j++) {
      if($temp1[$j][0] != $temp[$i][0] || $temp1[$j][1] != $temp[$i][1]) {
        $temp1[$j][0] = $temp[$i][0];
        $temp1[$j][1] = $temp[$i][1];
      }  
    }
  } else {
    $temp1[$j][0] = $temp[$i][0];
    $temp1[$j][1] = $temp[$i][1];
  }
}
print_r($temp1);
```

Comment: How does your attempt fail?  Have you investigated how it is flawed?

Comment: yes, I am not able to compare in the values in the new array $temp, I created.

Comment: In other langs its easy to implement this by just created a set and adding the elements to it. Since set take care of duplicates. But not sure how it can be implemented in PHP

Comment: Isn't `$temp1[$j][0] = $temp[$i][0]; $temp1[$j][1] = $temp[$i][1];` just `$temp1[$j] = [$temp[$i][0], $temp[$i][1]];`?

Comment: I believe you don't want to use inbuilt functions

Comment: yes you are right. I don't want to use any in build function

Comment: You should start by removing duplicates form the initial array (by iterating over it and adding the values in a new array *if* they are not present yet. Then you wouldn't need to iterate over $temp to remove its duplicates.

Comment: but $temp is a multidimensional  array

Comment: @mickmackusa if I do that, how will I compare later with those comma separated values

Comment: if you remove, all duplicates from `$a`, then `$temp` would contain your expected result after line 6, you wouldn't need the next lines of code.

Comment: It is not a comma separated value, it is the same pushing technique, just simplified.

Comment: @mickmackusa ya you are right.

Comment: @thchp how can I move the duplicates from $a, can you help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Start by removing duplicates from your array. Then you can generate all pairs easily.

```php
$a = [1,1,2];
$b = [];
$temp = [];

// if you want to do it yourself
for($i= 0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
    if (!in_array($a[$i], $b)) {
        $b[] = $a[$i];
    }
}

// if you want to use built-in
$b = array_values(array_unique($a));

for($i=0; $i<count($b); $i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<count($b);$j++) {
       $temp[] = array(0=>$b[$i],1=>$b[$j]);
    }
}

print_r($temp);
```